# Which sentence is grammatically better? There needs... or Something need

Tags: grammar

I assume both sentences are grammatically correct, but which one is better or more native?

1. There needs to be enough money to support public services.
2. Public services need enough money to be supported.

Comment: Which one do you prefer?

Comment: (2) doesn't seem right to me - 'being supported' isn't the job of the public services. Either _Public services need enough money to function efficiently_ or _The government needs enough money to support the public services._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they're both technically correct, (1) reads better than (2).

(2) would be better if 'Public Services' were an object in the sentence instead of the subject - something needs to support Public Services (the people, the government, etc). A good example is given in the comments already.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence sounds like a political position meaning that you support more money for public services.

The second sounds like a simple statement of fact, that public services cannot run without enough money. No opinion is suggested either way.